# не видит файла.Робота с Audio

Tags: java, аудио

```
package audio;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Audio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playSound();
    }
    static void playSound() {
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:/Surena.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104118/javax-sound-sampled-unsupportedaudiofileexception-could-not-get-audio-input-str